# How to use iterators and find/find_f to find a real value in a c++ vector of classes

Tags: c++, oop, object, vector, getter

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to get class association's to work correctly.

I have a vector of class objects, named Items. Each item has a values such as a name, price, etc. Inside the Items class there are setters and getters to change the values and to return them.

```
std::string choice; // users choice
ListOfOrders::iterator iter = orderList->end(); iter--; 
 // the last order inserted, ignore this this is used to get the last order so
 //we can pass the items to it (the order class has a vector of pointers
 //(items) that we are trying to pass to now.)

ListOfItems::iterator itemiter; // make the items iter
listItems(itemList); // function in the main that returns the list of items using the getters and a vector iterator.
while(choice != "x") // until the user quits
{
        // here is my prob, ofc, i can just compare the users entered choice of item (name) to the iterator because thats just returning a pointer to the class object, what i need to do it call the getName() getter from each of the objects and comparer that
    (*itemiter)->getName() = find (itemList->begin(), itemList->end(), choice);

    if (itemiter == itemList->end())
    {  
        std::cout << "sorry item not found please try again." << std::endl; 
    }
    else 
    {
        (*iter)->addItem(*itemiter); // pass the item object off to the order object's vector of items.
    }
}
```

I know something like this(see below(haven't compiled it, just quickly typed it to give you a idea)) could be used and it would work, but there must be a better way right?

```
std::string choice; // users choice
cin >> choice;
ListOfOrders::iterator iter = orderList->end(); iter--; // the last order inserted
if(lookForItem(choice))
{
    std::cout << "Yes\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "no\n";
}

bool lookForItem(std::string choice)
{
    ListOfItems::iterator itemiter; // make the items iter

    itemiter = itemList->begin();
    while(itemiter != itemList->end())
    {
        if((*itemiter)->getName() == choice)
        {
            (*iter)->addItem(*itemiter);
        }
        iter++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I looks like your container contains pointers to elements. That's the first problem.

Comment: typedef std::vector<Item*> ListOfItems; 
thats my typedef it holds a vector of the class Items?

Comment: It holds a vector of pointers to the items.

Comment: yes, i would like to compare what the user entered to the name of the item, this can be got from calling one of the getters from the items class.  ( like.. (*itemiter)->getName()  ) is there a way to use find or find_f to do this?

or even better would be a nicer way to get the user to choose a item from the list instead of typing the name in (cant use id's this is meant to be fully association based)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern C++, this is fairly simple with a lambda:

```
auto it = std::find_if(itemList.begin(), itemList.end(),
                       [&choice](Item const & x) { return x.name == choice; } );
```

It's not hard to spell out the lambda as a traditional predicate, of course:

```
struct FindItemByName
{
  FindItemByName(std::string const & s) : choice(s) { }
  bool operator()(Item const & x) const { return x.name == choice; }
private:
  std::string const & choice;
};

ListOfItems::iterator it
  = std::find_if(itemList.begin(), itemList.end(), FindItemByName(choice));
```

Comment: one thing im not to sure on here thou, what if name is a private varible from the Item class? can i call getName() like this?

Comment: @Makka: You can make the predicate a `friend`, or provide a public interface.

Comment: hey, sorry to be a idiot. i cant seem to get my head around this.

this is the part of my main that deals with it, 
`code` else if(choice == 2)
 {
  std::cout << "Please choose from one of the following customers and enter there name." << std::endl;
  listCustomers();// output the customerlist
  std::cin >> custInput;

  ListOfCustomers::iterator custiter = std::find_if(customerList->begin(), customerList->end(), FindCustomerByFirstName(custInput));
  custChoice = *custiter;

  std::cout << (custChoice)->getFirstName();
  system("PAUSE");

 }`

Comment: i added this to the main also..


struct FindCustomerByFirstName
{
  FindCustomerByFirstName(std::string const & s) : custInput(s) { }
  bool operator()(Customer const & x) const { return x.firstName == custInput; }
private:
  std::string const & custInput;
};

Comment: and then in the Customer class i added in 

friend struct FindCustomerByFirstName;

but when i come to compile i get


 >c:\users\makka\desktop\ordersystem copy3 ffs\ordersystem\main.cpp(245): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'FindCustomerByFirstName'
1>          Source or target has incomplete type

Answer (score 0):

Something close to this should work:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

struct Item {
  std::string name;
  // two items are equal, when their name is equal
  bool operator==(const Item& x) { return name == x.name; }
};

struct Cmp_item_by_name { 
  bool operator()(const Item& x, const std::string& y) { return x == y; }
};

typedef std::vector<Item> Items;
Items items;

Items::const_iterator
findItem(const std::string& name) {
 return std::find_if(items.begin(), items.end(), std::bind2nd(Cmp_item_by_name(), name));
}
```

This uses the deprecated `bind2nd`. Don't use this, as long as you don't understand it. We have great book lists on SO.